# How to know TLS Version of Connection where used and it will not downgrade?

Tags: sqlanywhere

If I'm using latest build of SQLAnywhere 16 than how to know which version of TLS where used in communication. I also wanted to assure that it will not downgrade to lesser version and will not use lesser than 1.1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no settings to change the version of TLS used by SQL Anywhere. However, all TLS applications will use the highest level of TLS supported by both sides. All SQL Anywhere versions starting with version 12 support TLS 1.2, and so a SQL Anywhere version 16 server will use TLS 1.2 as long as the client is from SQL Anywhere version 12 or later.

Comment: Thank you for your response Mr @graeme-perrow. Before accepting it as answer could you please tell me that it will not downgrade to lesser version of TLS and they will not use _TLS1.0_, if both server and client supports _TLS1.2_. Basically this is in regard of **Heart-Bleed** and **Poodle** Vulnerability.

Comment: As of version 16, if both client and server support TLS 1.2, then SQLA will use 1.2 and will __not__ downgrade. We do not support SSL 2 or 3 at all so POODLE is not possible and we have automated tests in place to make sure we are not susceptible to Heartbleed.

Comment: Thank You. @Graeme